# Repeating Items in RecyclerView

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I know this question has been asked before, but honestly, I can't find the right solution. I don't know why after scrolling the RecyclerView, adapter makes same data over and over again.

I have a project that uses retrofit to get data from an api-server and show it on a RecyclerView. I'm receiving data correctly and the received list doesn't have any repeated items. Just before passing the data to RecyclerAdapter in my Activity, I Log the data and still everything looks good. So I think the problem is the Adapter.

PS. While I'm running the app and scrolling RecyclerView to the end, "Log" inside the adapter, returns unique items. I think I have a mistake in binding data.

```
Log.i("test",data[position].toString())
```

Here is my Adapter:

```
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.example.cocktailrecipes.apiManager.model.category
import com.example.cocktailrecipes.databinding.TemplateRecyclerViewCategoryBinding

class CategoryAdapter(private val data: List<category.Drink>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter.Holder>() {

    lateinit var binding: TemplateRecyclerViewCategoryBinding

    inner class Holder(itemView: View) :  RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        fun bindData(drinkData:category.Drink) {

            binding.txtDrinkName.text = drinkData.strDrink

            Glide.with(binding.root)
                .load(drinkData.strDrinkThumb)
                .into(binding.imgDrink)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): Holder {
        binding = TemplateRecyclerViewCategoryBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),parent,false)
        return Holder(binding.root)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Holder, position: Int) {
        Log.i("test",data[position].toString())          
        holder.bindData(data[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return data.size
    }
}
```

Comment: Because your `binding` is **outside** your Holder class, so you are using the binding of the last-created Holder in the `bindData` function of every Holder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thx so much @Tenfour04

I use your advice and my problem solved:

```
class CategoryAdapter(private val data: List<category.Drink>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter.Holder>() {

    inner class Holder(private val binding: TemplateRecyclerViewCategoryBinding) :  RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bindData(drinkData:category.Drink) {

            binding.txtDrinkName.text = drinkData.strDrink

            Glide.with(binding.root)
                .load(drinkData.strDrinkThumb)
                .into(binding.imgDrink)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): Holder {
        val binding = TemplateRecyclerViewCategoryBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),parent,false)
        return Holder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Holder, position: Int) {
        Log.i("test",data[position].toString())
        holder.bindData(data[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return data.size
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the Holder make itemView a val, and then in bindData call:
itemView.txtDrinkName.text = drinkData.strDrink

binding is just a class property, I am not sure how it would know what view is associate with a specific holder.

Comment: That won't work without synthetics, which presumably they aren't using if they're using view binding.

Answer (score 0):

here is solution:-

```
@Override

public long getItemId(int position) {

    return position;
}

@Override

public int getItemViewType(int position) {

   return position;

}
```